# Javascript and Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, google-fusion-tables

Two related questions:

- Is there any good documentation on the Fusion Tables Javascript API? I've found a list of methods, but with little info on return values, semantics, or usage idioms.
- Is there any guidance (or suggested plugins or idioms) for integrating the FT Javascript API into a locally hosted Wordpress site?

Answer (score 2):

There is some documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/getting_started#JS

but I didn't find it very useful.
But this example, in the context of the Google Maps API I found very useful for the new API 1.0

https://googledrive.com/host/0B5KVZ6J1ohN_Q3ZqVkFGSGZ2cEE/custom%20markers%20code/customicons_viaApi.html

You'll need to view and save the source.  Also if you search the FT tag for JSONP you will find many examples using the old pre 1.0 API but the concepts are the same, just the AJAX end point has changed and the need for an apiKey.

The basic idea is that any FT query will return a JSON object with both columns and rows members, very much like a CSV response.

As the example above shows:

```
function onDataFetched(data) {
    var rows = data.rows;
    var cols = data.cols;
    ...
}
```